# Can't run printf() on a null-terminated string

Tags: c, gdb

printf() throws a segmentation fault when I pass a null-terminated string for some reason.

Here's a demonstration of my problem in GDB

```
     λ sudo gdb -q notesearch
    Reading symbols from notesearch...done.
    (gdb) break 53
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x400b32: file notesearch.c, line 53.
    (gdb) run
    Starting program: /home/frosty/hack/chapter_2/code/notesearch 
    [DEBUG] UserID: 0
    [DEBUG] File Descriptor: 3

    Breakpoint 1, print_notes (fd=3, uid=0, searchstring=0x7fff3daf7fc0 "")
        at notesearch.c:53
    53          printf("%s\n", note_buffer);
    (gdb) x/8xb note_buffer
    0x7feb5a997168: 0x68    0x65    0x6c    0x6c    0x6f    0x0a    0x00    0x00
    (gdb) x/s note_buffer
    0x7feb5a997168: "hello\n"
    (gdb) next

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    _dl_fixup (l=, reloc_arg=)
        at ../elf/dl-runtime.c:148
    148 ../elf/dl-runtime.c: No such file or directory.
    (gdb)
```

Here's the source code around the problem

```
    int print_notes(int fd, int uid, char *searchstring){
        int note_length = find_user_note(fd, uid);

        if (note_length == -1) 
            return 0; // End of file

        char* note_buffer;
        read(fd, note_buffer, note_length);

        note_buffer[note_length] = 0; // null terminator byte

        if(search_note(note_buffer, searchstring)) {
            printf("%s\n", note_buffer);
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: You have `char* note_buffer;`, but never allocate the memory. So when you use it, you're putting info in memory, but you have no clue where. Either allocate the memory first, or use a char array.

Comment: @AntonH Although, I am kinda confused on why it worked. If you looked in my gdb output, `read()` worked fine and read the expected string. 

Is it because it's in another area in the memory (other than the heap) and printf can't read that certain area of the memory?

Comment: "I am kinda confused on why it worked" --> Code broke the rules, writing with uninitialized `note_buffer`.  C does not require a sensible outcome - welcome to _Undefined Behavior_ (UB).

Comment: @TimothySamson It didn't work. It looked like it worked, but didn't really. Just because you see what you expected, does not mean that it worked. As "chux" said, Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot guys! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remember that in C, arrays are indexed from 0 through (length of array-1)

This line:

```
char* note_buffer;
```

declares an initialized pointer to character. I.E. its value depends on what ever trash is currently in memory at that location.  Such an action as accessing where that trash 'points' would be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Strongly suggest, after this line:

```
char* note_buffer;
```

inserting the following: (including the checking for a `malloc()` failure:

```
note_buffer = malloc( note_length+1 );
if( !note_buffer )
{
    perror( "malloc failed" ); 
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful
```

Note: without the `+1` on the call to `malloc()` the following line:

```
note_buffer[note_length] = 0;
```

would be setting a byte that is one past the end of the allocated area.  That would be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Also, a `0` has the bit pattern 0x000000000000000000000000 and a '\0' has the bit pattern 0x00000000.   the implicit conversion feature will save you in this instance, but do not rely on that feature, instead properly code literals.  so the line should be:

```
note_buffer[note_length] = '\0';
```

Note: `perror()` outputs the enclosed text string AND the reason the OS thinks the error occurred to `stderr`, which is where all error messages should be output.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. The note about the differences of the bit patterns of 0 and \0 is really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Null terminator is indicated by `\0` not `0`

`note_buffer[note_length] = 0;`

should be

`note_buffer[note_length] = '\0';`

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9JpJiJE79LgOUdXY1pxZUk1UkE/view?usp=sharing) proof

Comment: Could be related to the read() system call.
Replace this line:

`read(fd, note_buffer, note_length);` with this `read(fd, &note_buffer, note_length);`

Comment: [that compounded the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9JpJiJE79LgQkcwOURfMjl1dTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Also, i don't know how that would work. `&note_buffer` would be a pointer to a char pointer, and `read()` only asks for a char pointer

Comment: `0` and `'\0'` are both a zero with type `int`.  No difference.

Comment: @TimothySamson "read() only asks for a char pointer" --> `read()` requires a pointer to valid memory.